# How can I put control on another partial C# class?

Tags: c#, partial

I created a form with one button for testing. If the button is pressed, a message box will pop up and display Hello.

Then I add another class and moved the button click to this partial class, when I double click the button in the Designer form, it won't jump to the the partial class.

Anyone please help? Below are part of my code:

Form1.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Class1.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track.  Q: Did you ever assign the event handler for button1_Click() anywhere?

Comment: Yes. The event handle works fine when I put it on either class. But when I stop the program and double click the button on the Designer form, it won't jump to the right line when you put the handle in Class1.cs

Comment: you say 'when you put the handle in Class1.cs', can you paste that code?

Comment: Please see Class1.cs above. The handle is in Class1.cs already. There is also "            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
" statement added on the Form1 Designer so it calls the handle properly.

Comment: There's no such thing as a _partial class_. The `partial` keyword allows you to split the definition of a single class across multiple source files. For example in Windows Forms, the designer tools write their info in `FormNsme.designer.cs` and you get to write your code in `FormName.cs`. That way, there is less likelihood of a programmer messing up the specific format the designers need. At compile time, the code from both files is combined to describe a _single_ class

Comment: The designer is simply not capable of doing this, it only considers the main form file (the one whose name is visible in the Solution Explorer window).  If you want to partition event handling code better then consider user controls and classes derived from a toolbox control.